# Creating Individual PDFs from a Pivot Table using a macro

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am currently working on writing a macro to go through the Pivot Items in my pivot table and PDF them all as their respective Item names. The code below is stuck on line 26 '.CurrentPage = pi.Name', with the pop up stating: 'Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the CurrentPage Property of the PivotField Class'.

If I remove this line, it does cycle through the the items and save them as pdfs, but the item itself has not been selected by the macro so the pdf displays whatever is on the screen at that momeent.

I am new to VBA so may well be missing something simple, or may be well off! So any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub PDF_CGT()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    
    Set wksSource = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    
    Set PT = wksSource.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    
    Set pf = PT.PivotFields("PC")
    
    strPath = "Directory"
    
    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"
    
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
    
    PT.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    PT.PivotCache.Refresh
    
    With pf
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each pi In .PivotItems
            .CurrentPage = pi.Name
            wksSource.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & pi.Name & ".pdf"
        Next pi
        .ClearAllFilters
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the pivot field in fact a page field as it should be?

Comment: @Domenic Yes you are right - I figured it after i posted, the pivot table was not set up correctly. I am now stuck as there is a text box that needs to alter its position to one cell under the pivot table for each PDF (each pivot table changes in size). Any ideas?